# How to add health check request ip to load balancer security group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb, aws-security-group

I face an issue in AWS Elastic BeanStalk health checking. I deployed to my NodeJS application to AWS via elastic beanstalk. Then I give permission my elastic load balancer TCP 443 port accessible for only my domain that is routed by Cloudflare. Basically, My elastic load balancer is only accessible by Cloudflare,

[image]

Due to the fact that I use Cloudflare, AWS health checks can not be able to access to the endpoint of the load balancer. How can fix this issue? I don't want to open my load balancer TCP 443 port to all world people. I want to open TCP 443 port for the only Cloudflare and, at the same time, I want to use health check of AWS :)

Comment: You mean, the Route53's health checks?

Comment: not Route53, health check of the elastic beanstalk. Accessible from instances section, target group,

Comment: The ALB HCs are between ALB and instances. What Cloudflare has to do with them?

Comment: Normally you would setup SG of the instances to allow incoming traffic from the SG of the ALB. All this should be set by EB automatically.

Comment: @Marcin, I have just made the question more clarified. Simply I have added the cloudflare ips to loadbalancer's security group. Because of that, health checking can not able to access load balancer source URL. I want to change healthcheck url like `https ://mydomain.com/health`

Comment: I think I know what do you mean now. Did you deploy SSL cert on the ALB to use https health checks?

Comment: @Marcin, thanks for really helpful answers. I have just made a very stupid mistake, because of that it was giving. I am going to remove question :))

Comment: You can also provide an answer. Or I can do it if it was due to SSL?

Comment: @Marcin I had deployed SSL, the problem was not about the SSL. I supposed to health is working from public access. But I have just learned that it was not :)). It was working directly internally. There is no problem with Cloudflare or a security group or something like that. Because it checks health of the system in privately. Should I provide and answer or you should, or we should remove question?

Comment: You can provide an answer for your own question. Its better then deleting question. Others may have similar issues in future.

Answer (score 1):

If somebody reads this question in the future, I thought that the health-check is being executed, externally - accessing publicly. But I have just learned that it was not :)). It is being executed directly internally. There is no problem related to Cloudflare or the security group or any other thing!
If there is an error in your ELB regarding this, the problem is probably related to your codebase, not the security group or other configurations.